# Really no possible way to privately share libraries in Azure Notebooks?

Tags: azure-notebooks

I'm looking into which service to chose when it comes to Jupyter Notebooks hosted in the cloud.

Google Colaboratory (GCL) seems to be able to share privately (with people with Google Apps accounts) and real-time collaborate with them.

However, for me, Azure Notebooks (AZNB) has some benefits that I prefer over GCL – But I cannot NOT have the feature of sharing and collaborating. It seems like such obvious features, that I'm posing the question here – am I missing something right in front of me?

**Note:** For AZNB, I've found the "share" option, which forces the notebook to be public, and the "clone" option, which lets others work on a copy of my library. This is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now (29 sept 2018) - you can't get official way.

You can track this discussion here

https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues/329

I can suggest some option. Azure notebook service allow to use the terminal console, aznbsetup.sh file and have the preinstalled git.

You can put your notebooks in some private git repo, send the link and credential to your collaborators and tell some manual instructions

1. Create empty library
2. Open the terminal
3. Run the `cd ~/library` and `git clone your_private_repo`
4. All changes could be operated with standart git operations `pull`, `push` and etc

For autoupdates you can suggest the `aznbsetup.sh` with

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/library
git pull
```

It's worked for me.

Comment: so They would do the same in their end, to have their notebook lib sync (through git) with my lib? Not the clean way I hoped for, but probably the best existing solution.

Comment: Your contributors could push to bitbucket back, if you allow it in bitbucket (or another repo hosting) settings